# Opencart - how can i show available date in product page

Tags: php, date, opencart, product

want to use available date in product page after review or prod price...

how can i insert the available date from db

i edited catalog/controller/product/product.php

```
$available = $this->db->query("SELECT date_available FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
     if ($available->num_rows) {
        $date_available = $available->row['date_available'];   
          $this->data['date_available'] = date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($date_available));
     }else{
           $this->data['date_available'] = '';
     }
```

and catalog/view/theme/default/product/product.tpl

```
<?php echo $date_available; ?>
```

but nothing happened.

how can i show the available date in product page?
and how can i change the date format on that (like 04/12/2013 or 11.04.2013)

Hi everyone, i did what you're saying and got the date.
But it just show '01/01/1970' 
i added a column 'date_end' to db just after the 'date_available' column.
edited some files;

admin/controller/catalog/product.php
the old:

```
$this->data['entry_date_available'] = $this->language->get('entry_date_available');
    $this->data['entry_quantity'] = $this->language->get('entry_quantity');
```

the new:

```
$this->data['entry_date_available'] = $this->language->get('entry_date_available');
    $this->data['entry_date_end'] = $this->language->get('entry_date_end');
    $this->data['entry_quantity'] = $this->language->get('entry_quantity');
```

admin/language/mylanguage/catalog/product.php

added:

```
$_['entry_date_end']        = 'Bitiş Süresi';
```

admin/model/catalog/product.php
added `date_end = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_end']) . "'`

after every `date_available` 
 line 4 and 127

```
....d'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', date_end = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_end']) . "', manufacturer_id....
```

admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl

the old:

```
<tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_date_available; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="date_available" value="<?php echo $date_available; ?>" size="12" class="date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_dimension; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="length" value="<?php echo $length; ?>" size="4" />
            <input type="text" name="width" value="<?php echo $width; ?>" size="4" />
            <input type="text" name="height" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" size="4" /></td>
        </tr>
```

the new:

```
<tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_date_available; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="date_available" value="<?php echo $date_available; ?>" size="12" class="date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_date_end; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="date_end" value="<?php echo $date_end; ?>" size="12" class="date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_dimension; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="length" value="<?php echo $length; ?>" size="4" />
            <input type="text" name="width" value="<?php echo $width; ?>" size="4" />
            <input type="text" name="height" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" size="4" /></td>
        </tr>
```

so i want to show date_end but just got the '01/01/1970' in every product. 
So where is the mistake?

Comment: You make a query but do not get the results. http://tr2.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php. Check out that page it will explain. You need to select the rows. Also, what is $special_info?

Comment: edited the code. that was available

Comment: Please add the result of `print_r($available);` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the $product_info variable if you're editing in the template to get any of the returned product variables. For example, to show the date in short format you can use

```
<?php echo date_format($product_info['date_available'], $this->language->get('date_format_short')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did with the following tutorial.

[opencart tutorial](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=36625)

thanks everyone